Buildozer Unknown command/target android error when running build command
I am trying to build a financial analysis app using Kivy and Buildozer on Windows.
When I run the command buildozer -v android debug, I receive the error message: Unknown command/target android
What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it
OS windows 11,
Thank you in advance

I verified that Buildozer is installed using pip install buildozer
I checked that I am in the correct directory where the buildozer.spec file is located.
My buildozer.spec file has the target set to android
I ensured my environment includes Git and Java, and I’m using Python 3.12.


I don't think the 'windows' tag adds value here. It would primarily be if you are targeting Windows for your program.

I don't think you can compile for android on windows. See the documentation.
